# Building a template for Joomla: starting with HTML

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

I have done some WordPress templating, and I started with translating the design to a working HTML template. After that, I converted it to the WordPress theme.

But does Joomla work the same? Let's say that I have got a menu with the id #menu. If I make a new menu in Joomla, am I able to change the ID of that menu? I don't want to fiddle around with my CSS. Am I taking the right step to convert the design to HTML first, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You can do that, though usually I start with a blank Joomla template index.php file and figuring out the main regions of the page that I want. and defining those with `jdoc` tags and css. However what do you mean by not fiddling with the CSS? Joomla includes a lot of classes and ids you will need to deal with but it will also let you assign some of the in the administrator.  Protostar is a very simple template that you can make a copy of and move things around to understand how the templating works.

Comment: Thank you very much! I meant something like this:

I have a menu called #menu_top, but doesn't Joomla make it something like #menu_id11?

Thank you for you answer.

Comment: Your menu should be in a module.  Then use `jdoc:include` to pull in the menu module. com_menus will control the menu links, but the modules will control the layout (or be overridden in your template).  You would wrap the jdoc into probably a `<div></div>` to assign a class or id to it.  Joomla does do some automatic things to let you style individual menu links.